# Adding placeholder content in css unable to clear the text while entering the data in input field

Tags: html, css

Added content in palceholder using css but the problem is when i am adding the data in text box the placeholder content which i have added using css is not getting cleared.

```css
.applynowemail.contactemail:after {
  content: '*';
  position: absolute;
  color: #f00;
  /* margin-top: -36px;
  margin-left: 52px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="applynowemail contactemail">
  <input type="email" class="form-control emails" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email');?>" placeholder="Email" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you use jQuery?

Comment: @LucaKiebel i used only css to add astrick on placeholder while adding the text this astrick symbol is not getting cleared

Comment: My Question was about you tagging this as "jquery" while there was no sign of you using it

Comment: well ofcourse it's not getting cleared. because it's not a placeholder. it's a custom text you added with css

Comment: I placed your code in a runnable snippet, but I'm still not sure what the issue is - or even what you're asking to do

Comment: @LucaKiebel i have removed that changed  the tags

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have added that astrick mark through css,if i am trying to add a text in the textbox this astrick is not hiding it is displaying it should be hided while we are adding the tex

Comment: Do you want the asterisk to disappear when a user focuses on the input?

Comment: @ovokuro yes want to disappear that when user enters any value in textbox

Comment: The asterisk is a pseudoelement of the parent - you will not be able to achieve this with CSS.

Comment: @ovokuro then how can we disappear that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a CSS only solution:

1. It requires `.emails:valid + .required { display:none; }`
2. The asterisk to be in a `<span>` element

```css
.required {
  color: #f00;
  position:absolute;
  left:2px;
}
.applynowemail{
  position:relative;
}

.emails:valid + .required { display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="applynowemail contactemail">
  <input type="text" class="form-control emails" id="email" name="email" value="Some Email" placeholder="  Email" required>
  <span class="required">*</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, just edited. Your best bet is to position it absolutely there and add some spaces in the placeholder. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

I see that you tagged `jquery` to your question.

First of all you cannot achieve what you want only with CSS.

Second, jQuery you cannot change/style `pseudo-elements` like `:after` because they are NOT part of the DOM tree.

So, you need to add the custom `*` using also jQuery then hide it using the `hide()` method when the user enters a text inside the `input`

Also when you have absolutely position elements, do not use margins , but position them with `top right bottom left` instead

EDIT : edited with solution that is checking the `val.length` of the input to see if it's empty or not. So when the user deletes what he entered, the `*` will appear again

See snippet below

*I changed a bit your html and css but you can modify it as you want*

```js
var input = $("input")
$(input).before('<p class="star">*</p>')
$(input).on("keyup", function() {
  var val = $(input).val().length
  if (val > 0) {
    $('.star').hide()
  } else {
    $('.star').show()
  }
})
$(input).change(function() {

})
```

```css
p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #f00;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.applynowemail.contactemail {
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="applynowemail contactemail">
  <input type="email" class="form-control emails" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>

</div>
```

Comment: If enter any data in the text box and clear the astrick symbol is not displaying only the placeholder value is appearing

Comment: i don't understand. can you be more clear ?  my answer works like this : when a user enters something inside the input, the `*` disappears, that's what you wanted, wasn't it ?

Comment: Yes but the one which you posted if i clear the value which i have entered then the placeholder should look same like previous right but the astrick is not displaying in that